# Font scaling for Type 3 font

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe, adobe-xd

I am working with a pdf Document that uses Type3 fonts. The object stream has

```
3.6 -16.56 Td /F1 1 Tf
```

which specifies the font and font size.

I understand that the Type3 fonts are transformed from glyph to text space using FontMatrix.

Does the FontMatrix also impact the font size? If so, how?

Comment: The PDF font definition (including its font matrix!) is expected to define *"the glyphs at one standard size. This standard is arranged so that the nominal height of
tightly spaced lines of text is 1 unit. In the default user coordinate system, this means the standard
glyph size is 1 unit in user space, or 1 ⁄ 72 inch."* Obviously you can technically create a font definition with glyphs that in the user space go beyond that 1 unit, or that only cover a tiny portion of it, e.g. via the font matrix. But such font definitions would violate the expectations of the PDF spec.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the FontMatrix also impact the font size? If so, how?

No, it doesn’t. That would be completely wrong. *FontMatrix* is something fixed for the entire font, whereas font size may be different for every text output.

There is at least one more way of setting font size using text matrix:

```
/F1 1 Tf
% Font size is 30pt
30 0 0 30 10.455 219.89999 Tm
(F) Tj
```